# Задача на массивы C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите, товарищи:
Объявите два массива. Один размером в 100 элементов, второй в 50. Заполните первый массив случайными целыми числами. Во второй в порядке возрастания перенесите из первого все числа кратные 5. Если значения не будут помещаться во второй цикл – необходимо прекратить ввод. Если чисел будет недостаточно, свободные элементы массива заполните нулями

Comment: Задания за вас тут делать не будут, если что не получается в процессе, то помогут.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
vector<int> v(100), r;
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() { return random(); } ); 
copy_if (v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(r),[&r](int t) {return !(t%5) && r.size()<50;});
r.resize(50);
copy(r.begin(), r.end(), ostream_iterator<int> (std::cout," "));
```

P.S. в подавляющем большинстве случаев проверка на 50 элементов не нужна. Мат ожидание - 20 элементов.